# How to browse files on a boto3 space ? NoSuchKey error

Tags: django, amazon-s3, ckeditor, boto3, digital-ocean-spaces

I created a s3 space with Digitalocean. I upload files into this one with ckeditor in a django project.
I have no problem for uploading files but I meet a problem when I try to browse my server (to see if an image is already present)

Here is my code:

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client('s3', region_name='fra1', 
                              endpoint_url=settings.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
                              aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
                              aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                        )

resp = client.list_objects(Bucket=settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
```

And an error happend the line where I call the function list_objects

```
An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjects operation: Unknown
```

That's really stranger because I'm sure my settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME is the correct one.
Furthermore I'm sure there is no error in session.client because I use the same for uploading files, which works perfectly.

To make sure my bucket is the correct one I go to my AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL and got an XML with

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<Name>[MY BUCKET NAME]</Name>
<Prefix/>
<MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
<IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
```

And after that begins a list of `<Contents>`

Thank you for your help

Comment: `"http://s3.amazonaws.com/` is AWS endpoint, not DO. Can you clarify what do you want to do? Also what is the value of `settings.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL`?

Comment: I want to list all the files stored on my digital ocean space. 
Yes its AWS endpoint but spaces delivered by digital ocean are s3 spaces. I can't give you my AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL because its public for now but I can ensure you that I give the good one, because I get a success when uploading documents

Comment: may have you an advice ? according that Im using the correct endpoint